# NSOperationQueue cancels the current NSOperation when network switched

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsmutableurlrequest

I am uploading a video to server using POST method. Uploading a video is placed inside the `main()` of `NSOperation` .  After that it was queued up into `NSOperationQueue`.

Current operation gets failed when network was switched between wi-fi and cellular data.

How handle the network switching `NSOperation` failing issue.

Am using `sendSynchronousRequest:` for video upload

I tried using `AFNetworking` but results remains the same

Comment: I don't know if would solve your problem, but I strongly suggest you to do not use sync operation. If you don't want to mess around with NSURLConnection/NSURLSession use a third party lib such as AFNetworking 2.0

Comment: We tried implementing that too it doesn't solve our problem

Comment: I assume you are availing yourself of the `error` parameter of `NSURLConnection` call? When this request fails, what `NSError` do you receive?

Comment: yes i receive the error "The operation could not be completed "

Comment: You can identify the `NSError` for an upload that fails for this reason (by looking at the `code` and `domain` properties). So, you can modify your code to detect this error and perhaps try again if this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few suggestions here.

First of all you need to set up a mechanism for knowing when you are swicthing from WiFi to cellular. If so, you need to send the `cancel` message to the operation in order to cancel it.

Then, you need to transform your operations into an asynchronous operation (override `asynchronous` property, the old one was named `concurrent`). Each time you upload a chunk of data you need to verify if the operation has been cancelled, checking `isCancelled` property, and rolback if necessary.

Using a synchronous operations prevents you to cancel the task you are running.

A similar approach can be used with `NSUrlSession` (see `invalidateAndCancel` method). In this case, you could avoid to use operations to wrap an upload task on it.

Let me know if you need something else.